# Linking in julia fails

Tags: julia

First time that happens to me. I do not know why it complains in such an easy step. I have seen the same `ld` error in another instances, but never on julia.

```
 make
LINK usr/bin/julia
/usr/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/ld: /usr/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/../lib    /gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/libstdc++_nonshared.a(system_error44.o): undefined reference to symbol '_ZTVSt14error_category@@GLIBCXX_3.4.11'
/usr/opt/centos/devtoolset-1.1/root/usr/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/ld: note: '_ZTVSt14error_category@@GLIBCXX_3.4.11' is defined in DSO /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/home/adrian/julia/usr/bin/julia] Error 1
make: *** [julia-ui-release] Error 2
```

How do I change the linkers direction for the one suggested in the output?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/18666

Comment: Is there a direct way to add the path explicitly? Or maybe just to cancel this step? I remember that in old julia an automatic link was not created, therefore this was not an issue.

Comment: seems like mixed environments to me. What returns: `la -la /gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/libstdc++*` ?

Comment: Are you sure `la` is the command? I don't have it.